# Angular Router: URL Segment not found, when using query parameters

Tags: angular

I have a angular application where I use query params with routes.
I have the following route:

```
http://localhost:4200/m/additional-info/2
```

This works fine when I try it in the search bar, but when I type

```
http://localhost:4200/m/additional-info/2?type=individual-form
```

I get an error which says

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'm/additional->info/2%3Fform%3Dindividual-form'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'm/additional-info/2%3Fform%3Dindividual-form'
>      at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:4295)
>      at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:4259)
>      at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:29)
>      at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
>      at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
>      at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
>      at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
>      at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
>      at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
>      at TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:56)
>      at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
>      at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
>      at zone-evergreen.js:858
>      at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
>      at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
>      at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
>      at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
>      at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)

Routes in app.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './ui/desktop/desktop.module#DesktopModule'
  }, {
    path: 'm',
    loadChildren: './ui/mobile/mobile.module#MobileModule'
  }
];
```

routes in mobile module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MobileComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './core/core.module#CoreModule',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      }, {
        path: 'auth',
        loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
      }, {
        path: 'additional-info',
        loadChildren: './additional-info/additional-info.module#AdditionalInfoModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

routes in additional info module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdditionalInfoComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }, {
        path: '1',
        component: StepOneComponent
      },{
        path: '2',
        component: StepTwoComponent
      }, {
        path: 'success',
        component: SuccessComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

What could possibly be wrong??

PS: I am using lazy loaded routes because my application is quite huge and it's not possible to write all of them in one module. I heard it's because of the lazy loaded routes but not sure again.

Comment: Could you post the Routes definition (in app.module or app-routing.module)? also, are you using queryParams to parse the URL parameters?

Comment: Yes I am using queryParams to parse the URL parameters